# Mongodb will not start; no response with systemctl start mongodb (Mongo db version 4.0.0)

Tags: mongodb, fluentd

I am a new stack overflow, fluent and MongoDB user. I successfully installed MongoDB and mongo on Debian. However, when I try to start MongoDB in my command window I don't get any sort of response. When I then use this command systemctl status MongoDB.service I get the following response:

```
 mongodb.service - An object/document-oriented database
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mo 2018-07-09 17:01:40 CEST; 8s ago
 Docs: man:mongod(1)
 Process: 3393 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf (code=exited, status=4)
 Main PID: 3393 (code=exited, status=4)

Jul 09 17:01:40 stg2 systemd[1]: Started An object/document-oriented database.
Jul 09 17:01:40 stg2 mongod[3393]: all output going to: /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
Jul 09 17:01:40 stg2 systemd[1]: mongodb.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=4/NOPERMISSION
Jul 09 17:01:40 stg2 systemd[1]: Unit mongodb.service entered failed state.
```

For the life of me I don't understand why it will not start..I am OPEN TO ALL SOLUTIONS

Comment: Did you look at the logfile?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek are you referring to mongodb.log

Comment: Yes, as written in the message you quote yourself...

Comment: Also `status=4/NOPERMISSION` smells like a ... permission problem! double check ownership and permission of related files: configuration, logging, etc.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I will look into your suggestion

Comment: @PatrickMevzek  it seems as though I had different versions of Mongodb on my system. I simply purged and reinstalled the most recent version and all is well now. Thank you